# Is there a myth about someone who constantly creates their own demise?

Tags: greek, norse, myth-identification, roman, egyptian

Since this is certainly a common theme, I'm wondering if there is a myth about someone who ignorantly walks themselves repeatedly into ill-fate or their own misery. It would be like Sisyphus, but instead of being cursed to move the boulder, he did it on his own will and just repeatedly crushes himself with the boulder.

It can be really from any origin, I'm just convinced there has to be some myth that fits this theme, considering how much it plays out in modern life, and how accurate many myths were at describing things that... well, often play out in life.

I know this question is super broad but something tells me there has to be something pretty accurate out there. Thank you!

Comment: Sort of like Don Quixote. Or better yet, Wile E. Coyote.

Comment: Narcissus comes to mind, but his self-destruction was only the one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Epimetheus:**

His name literally means afterthought. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimetheus The brother of Prometheus, he never thought about the consequences of his actions, but instead reacted to things as they occurred. He and Prometheus were entrusted with the box containing all the evils of the world, and Epimetheus was warned by his brother not to accept gifts from the gods, who wanted to punish mankind for their crimes. Yet when the gods offered Pandora as a gift, he readily accepted (and we all know how that turned out.) Epimetheus was not really evil, he just didn't think and got in endless trouble because of it.

Comment: Thank you! I even read that he has a daughter, Metameleia, whose name literally means ""regret of what has occurred" for those that do not plan ahead will only feel sorrow when calamity strikes" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimetheus#:~:text=In%20Greek%20mythology%2C%20Epimetheus%20(%2F,Kerenyi%201951%2C%20p%20207).)